# Can Matrox TripleHead2Go support dual-mode DisplayPort?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport

I have an Alienware M18x r2 laptop, and am trying to hook up 3 external monitors to it in a [non-linear fashion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trXjX.png). I've discovered a product called [Matrox TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/) which *should* (hopefully?) let me do exactly this, but I'm still trying to work out the logistics of using it.

My laptop has the following output plugs: VGA, HDMI, and [dual-mode DisplayPort](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/35/DisplayPort_plus_plus.svg/708px-DisplayPort_plus_plus.svg.png). TripleHead2Go has a VGA model, but the achievable resolution is not as high as for the DisplayPort model. *(3x 1680x1050 versus 3x 1920x1080)*

What I'm wondering is: Is this setup feasible? Can the TripleHead2Go [DP](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/fr/products/gxm/th2go/displayport/) or [Digital SE](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/digital_se/) models support dual-mode DisplayPort? If so, do I need some kind of adapter to manage this?

Comment: Dual mode DisplayPort can generate TMDS and clock for single-link DVI/HDMI signaling with a simple line-level conversion dongle. If your hooking it up to a DisplayPort device you can just ignore this capability and treat it as straight DisplayPort.

Comment: @Brian Do I need an adapter to convert from the dual-mode DisplayPort (which I think uses a mini DP output plug?) to the regular DisplayPort, then?

Comment: Just needs the connector size that matches what your plugging each end into. So a DP to mini-DP cable would be fine.

Comment: @Brian Great, thanks. You could probably polish that into an answer if you wanted to. (Since it does seem that the dual-mode port is usable as a mini DP.)